# Unity HDRP Lighting way too bright but there is no light source

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, lighting

Alright so I spent hours working on a scene in unity HDRP but now the scene is overwhelmingly bright and I've literally deleted the direction light and its still so bright. Spent the last 5 hours trying to find a fix but can't. Can someone please chime in?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to make a new scene and reimport your models? If not try to check Global illumination I guess your model is emitting to much G.I.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about "Sky and Fog Volume". You seems likely having wrong Sky settings.
Or if you have post-progressing like bloom effect may over-expose.

And please also check your color space "linear", in Player Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Sky Reflection in your HDRP settings - [How you find it in the project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxoJ3.png).